# Тормозит Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

При создании Panel в Microsoft Visual Studio Windows Forms среда разработки начинает жутко тормозит, невозможно нормально создавать кнопки и прочее

Comment: Пробовали переустановку студии/windows?

Comment: Компьютер отвечает системным требованиям vs ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Можно попробовать восстановить студию, если ранее таких проблем не было
2. Подходит ли ПК под системные требования? Если нет, то ничем не поможешь. Переходител на менее требовательное IDE.
3. У меня подобная проблема была, когда я сидел на Windows 10 Привью. Проблема решилась переустановкой винды на релизную версию.

Comment: У меня процессор с частотой 2.6(4 ядра), 8 г оперативной памяти, я думаю этого должно хватить

Answer (score 1):

Зажмимаем `win + R`, в открывшемся поле вводим `resmon`, далее в мониторе ресурсов ищем процесс `devenv.exe`. Кликаем по нему ПКМ и выбираем `анализ цепочки ожидания` в то время, как VS "жутко тормозит".

Скорее всего, Вам просто не хватает ОЗУ, т.к. элементы панели автоматически подгружаются при попытке их использовать в проекте.

А по-хорошему Вам бы описать, какое железо, какая ОС и какая сборка Visual Studio и Windows / Linux /Mac.

Comment: Windows 8.1 x64, 2.60hz процессор, 8Г ОЗУ